# relationship one to many only working one side

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

i have a relationship one to many not working in one side.

My tables

```
`seguro_carro` (
  `id_seguro` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `matricula` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  `validade` DATE NOT NULL,
  `preco` DECIMAL(12,3) NOT NULL,
  `tipo_seguro` INT NOT NULL,
  `cliente` INT NOT NULL
)

`tipo_seguro_carro` (
  `id_tipo_seguro` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `descricao` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)
```

Models:
SeguroCarro.php

```
public function tipoSeguro()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\TipoSeguroCarro', 'id_tipo_seguro');
}
```

TipoSeguroCarro.php

```
public function seguros()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\SeguroCarro','tipo_seguro');
}
```

i can do `TipoSeguroCarro::find(x)->seguros` but not the other side like `SeguroCarro::find(x)->tipoSeguro`

and i can't understand why this is happening..
someone ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass `tipo_seguro` attribute instead of `id_tipo_seguro`, because Your foreign key is `tipo_seguro` in both relationships.

**Some explanation due to request:**

https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_belongsTo
`BelongsTo belongsTo( string $related, string $foreignKey = null, string $otherKey = null, string $relation = null)`

https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_hasMany
`HasMany hasMany( string $related, string $foreignKey = null, string $localKey = null)`

Both `belongsTo` and `hasMany` accepts second parameter as foreign key. So basicly, You have two fields involved - first is Your primary key (`id_tipo_seguro`) and second is foreign key (`tipo_seguro`). As mentioned before, both methods accept foreign key as second parameter.

Comment: but in my table tipo_seguro_carro is id_tipo_seguro the primary key..
why i pass the tipo_seguro in both relationships?
i have more one to many , like user have one or more SeguroCarro and in the relationships i say `hasMany('App\SeguroCarro', 'cliente');` and `belongsTo('App\Cliente', 'id_cliente');`

Comment: @syszen I updated my answer, have a look. If something still looks unclear, write it.

Comment: @Giendrius Kirsys okay, but my key to connect from the view of the table SeguroCarro is id_tipo_seguro on TipoSeguroCarro, no? thats why im confused , and why is the other relationship working but not this?

Comment: @syszen The real question is: does Your other relationship works properly. You don't have foreign key in `tipo_seguro_carro` table, just primary key. Your foreign key is in `seguro_carro` in both relationship "ends".

Comment: @Giendrius Kirsys can you refrase the answer pls?
imagine i have a user with many posts, and user have 'id_user' and posts have a foreign key 'fk_user' , so both relation belongTo and hasMany the foreign key is fk_user?

Comment: @syszen Long story short: When You are having relationship between two tables (without pivot), You are having primary key in one table (which matters) and foreign key in another table (which matters). Both `belongsTo` and `hasMany` requires second parameter to be foreign key.

Comment: @Giendrius Kirsys thank you for the explain, so both belongsTo and hasMany the foreign key is always the same rigth? (yes im having a big trouble to understand this very well)